# Why does "to" prop change when clicked?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a `Link` to the user profile page with a `to` prop set to `user/username`.
When I click it, it navigates to the profile page, and I notice that its value changes in dev tools to `user/user/username`, and a `user` is added to the url each time its clicked.
Why does this happen? And how to stop it?

[image]

Comment: Try `/user/username` instead

Comment: Wow! Thank you <3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as HMR said, Add a "/" to your Link component:

`<Link to='/user/username'>Link to user</Link>`

Otherwise you will create a relative link which will simply add the 'to' value to your current url.